# Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- Error in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
if ($_ =~ "buff\)" ) { print $_ ; }
```

While executing the above line, Perl is throwing following error:

```
Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/buff)
```

Can any one explain why this `)` close parenthesis is not working as normal string even if I am escaping it with a backslash?

Comment: Well, it works for me (perl5 v16.2). What version are you running?

Comment: amon: your edit corrected the code and made it work.

Comment: GIRI: What exactly are you trying to match? `buf)`? `"buff\)"`? `"buff)"`?

Comment: @amon: *Not* a good idea to fix the code in a question!

Comment: i want to match "buff)" . Because of ) paran having special meaning i escaped it with backslash . Now i tried with "=~ /buff\)/" its working

Comment: @innaM /@Borodin The double backslash was already there; see the markdown source of the revisions.

Comment: amon: I looked at the edit history. It seems to depend whether you look at the markdown diff or the .. other kind of diff. Weird. Does this mean we ought to close this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape the backslash:

```
=~ "buff\\)"
```

Or don't use the quotation marks at all, but regex notation:

```
=~ /buff\)/
```